# SharePoint Workflow to Send Reminder Email Problem

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm new to workflow and tried to create one in designer and came up to this:

```
If Current Item: Reminder Date equals Today
    Pause Until Current Item: Reminder Date
    then Email Current Item: Registrant
End of Workflow
```

Though in the workflow history it says email was sent, but I don't get the email.

I'm stuck here, so please point me to the right direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*Wait for field change* Current Item: Reminder Date *equals* Today
*then Email* Current Item: Registrant
*End Workflow*
```

This will work for you, use Wait for field change action unstead of if/Pause statement

Comment: Please mark it as solved if you think that it was helpfull

Comment: Please not that your initial workflow will never execute the Email Action because he will never enter the If Statement, When an item is created Both dates are not equal, so never getting the email when item is created.